# Is there a way to include an 'OR' statement in this method? (Ruby) Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to Ruby, and I'm trying to create a simple game to play Rock, Paper, Scissors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors)

I'm using TDD (RSpec), and I'm currently trying to code a method for player_one_wins? in order to pass the tests below.

```
    it "Player 1 chooses rock and WINS if Player 2 chooses scissors" do
        allow(player_one).to receive(:choice).and_return(:rock)
        allow(player_two).to receive(:choice).and_return(:scissors)
        expect(game.winner).to eq player_one.name 
    end

    it "Player 1 chooses paper and WINS if Player 2 chooses rock" do
        allow(player_one).to receive(:choice).and_return(:paper)
        allow(player_two).to receive(:choice).and_return(:rock) 
        expect(game.winner).to eq player_one.name
    end

    it "Player 1 chooses scissors and WINS if Player 2 chooses paper" do
        allow(player_one).to receive(:choice).and_return(:scissors)
        allow(player_two).to receive(:choice).and_return(:paper) 
        expect(game.winner).to eq player_one.name
    end
```

My problem is that when I define the method as follows with just the first line (and the other two commented out), it passes 1 of the 3 tests.

```
def winner
    return player_one.name if player_one_wins?
    player_two.name
end

def player_one_wins?
    player_one.choice == :rock && player_two.choice == :scissors
    # player_one.choice == :paper && player_two.choice == :rock
    # player_one.choice == :scissors && player_two.choice == :paper
end
```

But when I remove the hashtags that are commenting the other two lines out, all 3 of the 3 tests fail. What I am trying to achieve is that if any of the statements on any of the three lines of the method are true, then player_one_wins? should be true and so the 'winner' method will work. I have tried, unsuccessfully, using 'or' and ||

Sorry in advance if any of what I've said is plainly incorrect or nonsense - I'm new to Ruby, and trying to familiarise myself with all of the syntax etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to use or statements with the second method where you place parentheses around each && combination?

Comment: i.e. (x == y && z == a) || (x == b && z == y) and so on?

Comment: @Drew - Please post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(x == y && z == a) || (x == b && z == y)` and so on should do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy help! I did try that earlier, but the tests weren't running, and I only just realised it was because I was putting a || at the end of the very first line. So now I've removed that final ||, and now only one of the tests is failing - it seems that it's not taking into account the final line. So at the moment I have (x == y && z == a) || (x == b && z == y) || (x == c && z == y), and it's the final test for (x == c && z == y) which is failing. I'm thinking that maybe the || operator can't be used for more than two operands? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! And gotcha. I do believe that with the player_one_wins? method and with the following code: '(x == y && z == a) || (x == b && z == y) || (x == c && z == y)', it should evaluate correctly as long as the value of the variables are accurate. And welcome! Also, props on having some hella idiomatic code!

Comment: Also, when you write 'final test' where within the code are you referencing?

Comment: Or where within the above method definitions should I say

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! Learning to code from a completely non-tech background means that I can't help but try to write the code idiomatically - at the very least so that I can try and figure out what it all means! Unfortunately, it's not working for me, and I can't see any errors in my variables at the moment. I think I'll have take a break and take a fresh look at it again in an hour or so.

Comment: Oops, wasn't looking at the failed test closely enough - I located the error and fixed it! It was in my test. All tests are passing now. I had been expecting that player1 with scissors and player2 with paper would cause player2 to win. Doh! Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Also, if this answered your initial question, feel free to accept it as an answer and maybe note that it directly led you to answer?

Comment: Just accepted it as the answer, but I'm not sure how to note that it led directly to the answer. Will try and figure this out now!

Comment: Thank you! Also, *indirectly and I do believe this convo in the comments should help!